# DIV tags not being properly nested

Tags: css, layout, html, nested

I have created some `<div>` tags and am setting it to contain two `<div>` tags that are floated to both sides of the `<div>`.
I noticed when I tried to set a background color that the containing `<div>` was not properly wrapping around the `<div>`s that its supposed to contain.
I would like to know why this happens.

I have seen a similar question here [Why are these Div tags not nesting properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611220/why-are-these-div-tags-not-nesting-properly) but no one has explained why this happens in any of the answers.

Comment: Provide the markup please. Also, remember that floating divs doesn't have width, you have to explicitly set it.

Comment: @Ben, seems like a pretty common float / document flow problem to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you keep parents of floated elements from collapsing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you float the inner divs, you take them out of the normal document flow, so basically your containing div has no content and no height.

You can solve it by adding a:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to the outer div (just one possible solution).

Comment: Jeroen's solution works well. You can also use an empty element such as <br class=clear /> under your inner divs and put clear:both for the clear class in your stylesheet. (if hidden overflow is a problem for your layout)

Comment: @edl, true, but I prefer the overflow solution as `clear:both` tends to clear more than just the containing box.

Comment: agreed. :) I also prefer the overflow solution. Just depends on the individual application.

Comment: @edl, absolutely, there´s no magic bullet for every situation.

Answer (score 0):

Add `style="overflow:hidden;width:100%"` to the containing div

I think `style="overflow:hidden;"` is enough for most browswers, I seem to remember some IE needing the width to be set.

Comment: Only when in quirksmode and you don't want to have that.

Comment: @BalusC, no, in IE6 (all modes) the element needs to get *layout* to contain its floats. Setting a `width` will do that, though I prefer `zoom: 1`. In IE7, `overflow` already gives the element layout.

Comment: @mercator: Oh, I forgot that IE6 ever existed. But yes, you're right :)